# add an image in listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Hi I would like to add more images in my list view as this code below only displays image 1 and 2 continuously in each row. What I want to do is display a different image for each different row. Here is mycode below;

Thanks for any help. I am not good at java please change the code where necessary and I can then refer to it.

public class starters extends ListActivity
{
    private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Bitmap mIcon1;
        private Bitmap mIcon2;
        private Bitmap mIcon3;
        private Bitmap mIcon4;
        private Bitmap mIcon5;
        private Bitmap mIcon6;
        private Bitmap mIcon7;
        private Bitmap mIcon8;
        private Bitmap mIcon9;
        private Bitmap mIcon10;

```
    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Icons bound to the rows.
        mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.starters1);
        mIcon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.starters2);
        mIcon3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.starters3);
        mIcon4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.starters4);
        mIcon5 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.starters5);
        mIcon6 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.starters6);
        mIcon7 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.starters7);
        mIcon8 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.starters8);
        mIcon9 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.starters9);
        mIcon10 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.starters10);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return DATA.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
        // to findViewById() on each row.
        ViewHolder holder;

        // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
        // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
        // by ListView is null.
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.starters, null);

            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text01);
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon01);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
        holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
       holder.icon.setImageBitmap((position & 1) ==1 ? mIcon1 : mIcon2);


         return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView icon;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
}

private static final String[] DATA = {
    "Original nachos", "Toasted chicken and cheese quesadillas", "Chicken, lime and coriander nachos",
    "Spicy bean and cheese quesadillas", "Tuna and corn quesadillas", "Cheesy bean and sweetcorn nachos", "Crispy chicken, avocado and lime salad", "Beef and baby corn tostada",
    "Spicy mexican rice with chicken and prawns", "Chilli potato boats"};
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do is display a different image for each different row

Then put a different image in each row. You have control over what goes in each row via `getView()`. Your current implementation iterates between two different images -- change that logic to be whatever works for your app.

[Here is a free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books that goes into greater detail on this.